# Save features and attributes as WFS in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs-t

I want to create some squared features with OpenLayers 4, add attributes to each feature and want to save them on the GeoServer to load them later on to another map. I am able to create the features, add attributes to them, read the attributes again and load a layers as WFS again.

My only problem is to save the created features to the GeoServer. I figured out that saving and loading should be possible with WFS-t. I found some examples online but they don't seem to work properly.

When i send the feature to the GeoServer with the function `transactWFS` at line 133 I get the Error 
`"org.geoserver.wfs.WFSTransactionException: Feature type 'Stairways' is not available"` in the GeoServer log file. The Layer Stairways exists on the GeoServer.
This is the XML file that is sent:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <Insert>
    <Stairways xmlns="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs">
      <geometry>
        <Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:3857">
          <exterior>
            <LinearRing srsName="EPSG:3857">
              <posList>1528915.8154546698
                    6627851.731194374 1528917.9110709063
                    6627858.932471524 1528925.1123480562
                    6627856.836855288 1528923.0167318196
                    6627849.635578138 1528915.8154546698
                    6627851.731194374</posList>
            </LinearRing>
          </exterior>                                                   
        </Polygon>
      </geometry>
    </Stairways>
  </Insert>       
</Transaction>
```

This is my whole Code:

```
   GridSource.addFeature(NewSquare);

    var attr = {};
    var key = "TestAttr";
    attr[key] = "This is a Test";

    NewSquare.attributes = attr; 
    transactWFS('insert', NewSquare);        
  }



  var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();

  var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
      featureNS: gs.wfs,
      featurePrefix: 'HTW_Erd',
      featureType: 'Stairways',
      srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
  });

  var xs = new XMLSerializer();


  var transactWFS = function (mode, f) {
      var node;
      switch (mode) {
          case 'insert':
              node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f], null, null, formatGML);
              break;
          case 'update':
              node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [f], null, formatGML);
              break;
          case 'delete':
              node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, [f], formatGML);
              break;
      }
      var payload = xs.serializeToString(node);
      $.ajax(gs.ows, {
          service: 'WFS',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'xml',
          processData: false,
          contentType: 'text/xml',
          data: payload,
          error: function(e) {
              var errorMsg = e? (e.status + ' ' + e.statusText) : "";
              alert('Error saving this feature to GeoServer. \n\n'
                  + errorMsg);
          }
      }).done();

  };
```

Edit:
I saw in the log file that i wasnt allowed to write on that layer so i set the permissions. I also changed the projection of the GridLayer to 3857 and the name of the feature to geometry. But that didn't help either. I now don't get any errors and the log looks like this:

```
2017-07-30 23:47:07,676 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2017-07-30 23:47:07,709 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2017-07-30 23:47:07,744 INFO [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: {https://localhost:8080/geoserver/htw_erd}Stairways PreInsert
2017-07-30 23:47:07,749 INFO [geoserver.gwc] - DataStoreChange: {https://localhost:8080/geoserver/htw_erd}Stairways PostInsert
2017-07-30 23:47:07,751 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        filter = [  bbox POLYGON ((1528628.1984057308 6627469.038650171, 1528628.1984057308 6628141.798427672, 1529548.9368749668 6628141.798427672, 1529548.9368749668 6627469.038650171, 1528628.1984057308 6627469.038650171)) ]
        srsName = EPSG:3857
        typeName[0] = {https://localhost:8080/geoserver/htw_erd}Stairways
    outputFormat = application/json
    resultType = results
2017-07-30 23:47:07,754 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2017-07-30 23:47:07,801 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: transaction
    service = WFS
    version = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    group[0] = wfs:insert=net.opengis.wfs.impl.InsertElementTypeImpl@e314ac (feature: [SimpleFeatureImpl:Stairways=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: the_geom<the_geom id=fid--2e9bc012_15d95498172_-7ffe>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: id<id id=fid--2e9bc012_15d95498172_-7ffe>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: indoor_are<indoor_are id=fid--2e9bc012_15d95498172_-7ffe>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: indoor_lev<indoor_lev id=fid--2e9bc012_15d95498172_-7ffe>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: indoor_l_1<indoor_l_1 id=fid--2e9bc012_15d95498172_-7ffe>=null]], handle: null, idgen: <unset>, inputFormat: <unset>, srsName: null)
    insert[0]:
        feature[0] = SimpleFeatureImpl:Stairways=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: the_geom<the_geom id=fid--2e9bc012_15d95498172_-7ffe>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: id<id id=fid--2e9bc012_15d95498172_-7ffe>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: indoor_are<indoor_are id=fid--2e9bc012_15d95498172_-7ffe>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: indoor_lev<indoor_lev id=fid--2e9bc012_15d95498172_-7ffe>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: indoor_l_1<indoor_l_1 id=fid--2e9bc012_15d95498172_-7ffe>=null]
        idgen = GenerateNew
        inputFormat = text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1
    releaseAction = ALL
```

All the features that are already in the Layer named 'the_geom', renaming the feature to the_geom doesn't help.

Edit 2:
This is the Output

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="service">
<ows:ExceptionText>No service: ( wfs\ )</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

I have to add that I dont have the default layers anymore, so i dont have the topp workgroup and the layer states anymore.

Edit 3: 
This is the Output for this link: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=HTW_Erd:Stairways

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:HTW_Erd="https://localhost:8080/geoserver/htw_erd" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://localhost:8080/geoserver/htw_erd">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
<xsd:complexType name="StairwaysType">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="id" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="indoor_are" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="indoor_lev" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="indoor_l_1" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="Stairways" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="HTW_Erd:StairwaysType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: you need to run it for your layer not topp:states - I know what it's attributes are!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling GeoServer that the namespace for your feature is `xmlns="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs"` (or `gs.wfs`) when it should be the URI associated with your workspace that contains the `Stairways` featuretype.

I would also check to be sure that the layer name really starts with a capital S as it is case sensitive.

**EDIT**

You will need to set the geometry field name using

```
 geometryName: "the_geom",
```

in your GML format.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i used the URI of my Workspace and now there is no error anymore. But the Problem is that when I import the Stairways layer after adding and uploading the feature, the newly added feature dosent appear on that layer and also no attributes. There only appear the already added features that i uploaded manualy.

Comment: Then you need to look in the log file to see if it says anything. Next check that the geometry of your layer is called geometry and that it is in 3857

Comment: Edited the main post

Comment: Now i get the error "java.io.IOException: Dbf has extra record" in the log files and i cant find a solution online.

Comment: what does describeFeature on the layer you are trying to write to say

Comment: I dont know what you mean with describeFeature or where to find it.

Comment: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html#describefeaturetype

Comment: It says "error on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error" on the page and in console error 404 (Not Found) when i get the describeFeature of the Stairways Layer. When i want to get the describeFeature of all Layers it shows all layers with no error.

Comment: your url should be http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?
  service=wfs&
  version=1.1.0&
  request=DescribeFeatureType&
  typeNames=HTW_Erd:Stariways

Comment: That link works, I used HTW_Erd:StairwaysType because that was what it says under type. But with your link it showes the information from all layers like with the link without typeNames defined.

Comment: sorry cut and paste error - should be typename  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs\?service=wfs\&version=1.1.0\&request=DescribeFeatureType\&typeName=topp:states  please paste that output into your question

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: But you queried the wrong layer. It's a way of finding out what your layer should look like.

Comment: When I change the topp:states to HTW_Erd:Stairways it shows the same as with topp:states

Comment: Make sure you delete any spaces that may have been inserted

Comment: I deleted all the spaces and i also tried it by deleting all the backslashes in the variables of the link and then it shows an xml with the error "Could not determine geoserver request from http request org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter$AdvancedDispatchHttpRequest@c69290"

Comment: Either you are using a broken url or your server is broken.

Comment: By copying the used link in this field i just noticed that there where hidden signes in that link. Now it shows a list of the attributes of the layer as an xml. I posted it in the question.

Comment: Do you have any more ideas to fix this problem?

Comment: I think you need to start a new question with the feature schema (result form the describefeature request) and the XML you are sending to GeoServer and the exact error given in the logs