# Error inserting features to GeoServer WFS Layer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs

when i try to insert a feature into an existing WFS Layer on my GeoServer i get the error "Error performing insert: Dbf has extra record" in the log of the GeoServer. I used the following code to insert a feature and get the WFS layer after that.

```
  var GeoServerAddr = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/';
  var wmsLayerName = 'Stairways';
  var wmsWorkgroupName = 'HTW_Erd';

  var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'black', width: 2});
  var fill = new ol.style.Fill({color: 'red'});  
  var styles = {
  'star': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
      fill: fill,
      stroke: stroke,
      points: 5,
      radius: 10,
      radius2: 4,
      angle: 0
    })
  })};

  //OSM Layer einbinden
  var osmlayer = new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()});

  //Layer für das Grid zum Speichern der Wände
  var GridSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      projection: 'EPSG:3857',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  });

  var GridLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: GridSource
  });


  var featureSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
      url: function(extent) {
        return gs.wfs + '?service=WFS&' +
            'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=' + wmsWorkgroupName + ':' + wmsLayerName +
            '&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
            'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
      },
      strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
  });

  var featureLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: featureSource,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
          width: 2
        })
      })
  });

  var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine();

  //Layer Z-Index festlegen
  osmlayer.setZIndex(0);
  //GridLayer.setZIndex(5);


  var layers = [osmlayer]; //, GridLayer

  //Sicht auf HTW Zentrieren
  var view = new ol.View({
      center: [1529088.5676403488, 6627805.4185389215],
      zoom: 18,
      rotation: 6
  });


  var map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
      attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
        collapsible: false
      })
    }).extend([
      scaleLineControl
    ]),
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    view: view
  });


  var gs = {
      wfs: GeoServerAddr + wmsWorkgroupName + '/wfs',
      ows: GeoServerAddr + wmsWorkgroupName + '/ows'
  };


  function init() { //Wird beim laden der Seite aufgerufen
    drawGrid([1528915.8154546698,6627851.731194374], [1529106.647853138,6628043.728236666], 5, null);     
    //getWfsFeaturesLayer();
  }


  map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {    
    console.log("TestAttr: " + getVectorFeatureInfo(featureLayer, evt.pixel, "TestAttr"));
  });


  var drawGrid = function(TlCoord, BrCoord, Size, apPositions) {
    var GridSize = Size * 1.5;
    var NewSquare = drawSquare(TlCoord, GridSize);
    NewSquare.getGeometry().rotate(map.getView().getRotation(), TlCoord);


    GridSource.addFeature(NewSquare);

    var attr = {};
    var key = "TestAttr";
    attr[key] = "This is a Test";

    NewSquare.attributes = attr; 
    transactWFS('insert', NewSquare);        
  }


  var drawSquare = function(StartCoord, size) {
    var polyCoords = [[StartCoord, [StartCoord[0], StartCoord[1] + size], [StartCoord[0] + size, StartCoord[1] + size], [StartCoord[0] + size, StartCoord[1]], StartCoord]];

    var polygonFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon(polyCoords),
        name: 'geometry'
    });

    return polygonFeature;     
  }   


  var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();

  var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
      featureNS: 'https://localhost:8080/geoserver/htw_erd',
      featurePrefix: wmsWorkgroupName,
      featureType: wmsLayerName,
      srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
      geometryName: "the_geom"
  });

  var xs = new XMLSerializer();


  var transactWFS = function (mode, f) {
      var node;
      switch (mode) {
          case 'insert':
              node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f], null, null, formatGML);
              break;
          case 'update':
              node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [f], null, formatGML);
              break;
          case 'delete':
              node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, [f], formatGML);
              break;
      }
      var payload = xs.serializeToString(node);
      $.ajax(gs.ows, {
          service: 'WFS',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'xml',
          processData: false,
          contentType: 'text/xml',
          data: payload,
          error: function(e) {
              var errorMsg = e? (e.status + ' ' + e.statusText) : "";
              alert('Error saving this feature to GeoServer. \n\n'
                  + errorMsg);
          }
      }).done();

  };


  var getVectorFeatureInfo = function(featureLayer, pixel, infoKey) {
    var features = [];

    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
      features.push(feature);
    }, null, function(layer) {
      return layer === featureLayer;
    });

    console.log("Features Found: " + features.length);
    if (features.length > 0) {
      for(var i = 0; i < features.length; i++)
      {
        if (typeof features[i].attributes[infoKey] !== 'undefined')
        {
          console.log("Found Attribute: " + infoKey + ": " + features[i].attributes[infoKey]);
          return features[i].attributes[infoKey];
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log("No Info Aviable");
      return "None"
    }
  }


  var getWfsFeaturesLayer = function() { 

    featureSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
      url: function(extent) {
        return gs.wfs + '?service=WFS&' +
            'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=' + wmsWorkgroupName + ':' + wmsLayerName +
            '&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
            'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
      },
      strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    });

    featureLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: featureSource,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
          width: 2
        })
      })
    });

    //Add Marker to Layer so it is visible that it was loaded correct
    var feature;
    feature = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([1528915.8154546698, 6627851.731194374]));
    feature.setStyle(styles['star']); 
    featureSource.addFeature(feature);


    map.addLayer(featureLayer);
    featureLayer.setZIndex(5);
  }


</script>
```

The describefeature Request shows the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:HTW_Erd="https://localhost:8080/geoserver/htw_erd" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://localhost:8080/geoserver/htw_erd">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="StairwaysType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="id" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="indoor_are" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="indoor_lev" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="indoor_l_1" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="Stairways" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="HTW_Erd:StairwaysType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

This seems to be normal. I already discussed a problem that lead to this problem in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250428/save-features-and-attributes-as-wfs-in-geoserver) question

I hope someone can help me solve this problem too.

Edit:

This is the Post XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <Insert>
    <Stairways xmlns="https://localhost:8080/geoserver/htw_erd">
      <geometry>
        <Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:3857">
          <exterior>
            <LinearRing srsName="EPSG:3857">
              <posList>1528915.8154546698 6627851.731194374
1528917.9110709063 6627858.932471524 1528925.1123480562 6627856.836855288
1528923.0167318196 6627849.635578138 1528915.8154546698
6627851.731194374</posList>
            </LinearRing>
          </exterior>
        </Polygon>
      </geometry>
      <name>geometry</name>
    </Stairways>
  </Insert>
</Transaction>
```

This is the Response of the Get:

```
<ows:exception exceptioncode="NoApplicableCode">
<ows:exceptiontext>
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Dbf has extra record
java.io.IOException: Dbf has extra record
Dbf has extra record
</ows:exceptiontext>
</ows:exception>
```

Edit 2:

So i changed the polygon attributes to the attributes from the schema from this link `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=HTW_Erd:Stairways`      to this

```
 var polygonFeature = new ol.Feature({
    'the_geom': new ol.geom.Polygon(polyCoords),
    'id': 100,
    'indoor_are': 'whatever value you need',
    'indoor_lev': '0',
    'indoor_l_1': 'Erdgeschoss',
});
```

But the error is still the same

Edit:

I updated my GeoServer to the Version 2.11.2 just to be sure i am not using an old version and tried to fix the XML but i always generate this XML file:

```
<Transaction 
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" 
service="WFS" version="1.1.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <Insert>
    <Stairways xmlns="https://localhost:8080/geoserver/htw_erd">
      <the_geom>
        <Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:3857"
          <exterior>
            <LinearRing srsName="EPSG:3857">
              <posList>1528915.8154546698 6627851.731194374 1528915.8154546698 6627859.231194374 1528923.3154546698 6627859.231194374 1528923.3154546698 6627851.731194374 1528915.8154546698 6627851.731194374</posList>
            </LinearRing>
          </exterior>
        </Polygon>
      </the_geom>
      <id>100</id>
      <indoor_are>whatever value you need</indoor_are>
      <indoor_lev>0</indoor_lev>
      <indoor_l_1>Erdgeschoss</indoor_l_1>
    </Stairways>
  </Insert>
</Transaction>
```

The describefeature request generates this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:HTW_Erd="https://localhost:8080/geoserver/htw_erd" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://localhost:8080/geoserver/htw_erd" debug="true">
<script id="FirebugLite" firebugIgnore="true" extension="Chrome"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
<xsd:complexType name="StairwaysType">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="id" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="indoor_are" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="indoor_lev" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="indoor_l_1" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="Stairways" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="HTW_Erd:StairwaysType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

So it should fit togehter but i still get the same error.

Comment: please add the xml being sent to geoserver (so we can see what the extra attribute is) and the complete geotools debug level log message.

Comment: Again you need to check the XML being sent to the server to see if it matches, or include it in the question

Comment: I included the xml that is send to the server

Comment: try leaving id out

Comment: That didnt helped ether. OpenLayers sends the exact same XML only without the id tag. I also tried to just send feature with the_geom tag and no extra tags but that also didnt helped. I always get the error "Error performing insert: Dbf has extra record"

Comment: Try using a postgis datastore instead of a shapefile

Comment: Using PostGis solved the problem. Now i get the response <wfs:totalInserted>1</wfs:totalInserted> so it inserted the rectangle i wanted to insert. Now i just need to find a way to show the layer on the map.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the XML transaction that you are posting, it contains two attributes `geometry` and `name`. Neither of these attributes are in the schema that describes what the server is expecting (i.e. `the_geom`, `id`, `indoor_are`,`indoor_lev` & `indoor_l_1`).

Therefore GeoServer will do two things, first adds a new geometry attribute to the feature and then adds a new attribute to the feature called `name`. When it then tries to save the feature to the Shapefile it fails as the feature doesn't fit the schema of the Shapefile. As it happens it complains about the extra column in the attributes first. In fact for a shapefile it ignores all geometry attributes that are not called `the_geom` anyway.

So you need to modify your code to set the geometry column name to `the_geom` and then set the attributes you do have to new values. I'm not an OpenLayers expert but look at changing:

```
var polygonFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon(polyCoords),
    name: 'geometry'
})
```

to:

```
var polygonFeature = new ol.Feature({
    'the_geom': new ol.geom.Polygon(polyCoords),
    'level_are': 'whatever value you need'
})
```

You may need to fiddle with it until the XML you are sending looks right.

Comment: Edited the question